# Is it possible to connect xaml.cs to corrsponding xaml in VS2017 csproj format?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017, csproj

Because of huge advantages in NuGet packaging, I transformed the `csproj` file of a C# library to the new Visual Studio 2017 format as described here:
[Old csproj to new csproj: Visual Studio 2017 upgrade guide](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/).

Now all the `xaml.cs` and `xaml` files of my WPF usercontrols are being shown separatedly side by side and not in a structure (`xaml.cs` "inside" `xaml`). Additionally I can not switch between them via the context menu commands "view code" or "view designer".

I found out that I can solve the structural display with adding appropriate entries in the `csproj` file:

```
<Compile Include="SomeView.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>SomeView.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

After having saved the `csproj` file, it takes a second or two and then the two items are visually structured in the project explorer view.
I still cannot switch between them via context menu commands, though.

Additionally I get the error `NETSDK1022` when compiling, telling about those compile elements being doubled now (the new project format automatically adds all suitable files). It is possible to disable this mechanism via setting `EnableDefaultCompileItems` to `false`, which works.

Is there a better way to "bind" the xaml and it's code-behind file for the new VS2017 project format?

(maybe this is one of the issues why the new project format is not yet released for window projects...)

Comment: The article you linked clearly states the list of project types supported. And tells you wpf is not. You could try vs2019 preview, but i think it would be better to wait until you can create a wpf app targetting .net core 3 and it's template works. Imo it's too early to risk moving to net core 3 for an app you intend releasing.

Comment: @Andy you're right, its written in the article. It is some times ago that I read the introduction....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Include` with `Update`.

Starting from your point

> the new project format automatically adds all suitable files

Because this point, usually prefer to use `Update` instead of `Include`. Just this.

Assuming all files are included by default, when you use the word "Include", you are adding a file that already exists. But if you use the word "Update", you update the file that is already included.

Comment: Thanks, this works for the structured view in the project explorer. It is still not possible to switch between xaml view and code-behind via context menu, but this isn't that great catastrophe. I will either live with it, or revert back to the old project format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think switching to the new project format is officially supported for WPF projects targeting the .NET Framework. It will be supported in Visual Studio 2019 when you target .NET Core 3 though.

There is this new `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` SDK that builds .NET Core WPF projects including XAML files using the following minimal `.csproj` file available in the [preview](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2018/12/15/wpf-on-net-core/) blog post for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this information. For now it is too delicate to switch to .NET core 3, because this library is only a small part of the whole application (and I don't want to mix things, if this is even possible). But the news is great that WPF comes to .NET core!